# combining a multiple queries into a single query (in SQL Server, with variables?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I'd like to apply the following query to two other circ_slip values ('payment' and 'refund') for a large number of locations.

```
delete from circ_slip_field 
where location = 'NEW LOCATION' and circ_slip = 'waive'
go
declare @copy_loc varchar(7), @new_loc varchar(7) 
select @copy_loc = 'OLD LOCATION' 
select @new_loc = 'NEW LOCATION'
insert circ_slip_field
       (circ_slip,location,section,ord,circ_slip_field_type,label,field_column,
        append_to_prev,justify,max_field_len,min_field_len,data_mask)
select  circ_slip,@new_loc,section,ord,circ_slip_field_type,label,field_column,
        append_to_prev,justify,max_field_len,min_field_len,data_mask
from circ_slip_field 
where circ_slip = 'waive' and location = @copy_loc
```

So I added the following line to the beginning and then copied the original query three times, replacing the two instances of 'waive' with 'payment' and 'refund' respectively.

```
 declare @copy_loc varchar(7), @new_loc varchar(7) 
 select @copy_loc = 'COPY LOCATION' 
 select @new_loc = 'NEW LOCATION'
```

I also removed the two select variable statements (@copy_loc and @new_loc) since they have already been declared.

Any thoughts on why this did not work for me?  I would be greatly appreciative.  Needless to say I'm quite new to SQL in general.

** EDIT:  by "did not work" I meant the query ran without errors but did not make any changes to the NEW LOCATION.

*** 2nd EDIT: I think the issue may be with the "go" command.  In order to have the variables work throughout I need to remove the 'go' from my three replicated queries.

Comment: "_Any thoughts on why this did not work for me?_" And how do you define "did not work"?

Comment: As we have no idea what you're talking about when you say "did not work for me", it's very hard to speculate on what the reasons might be. We can't read your mind, and we don't have your data or the rest of your code in front of us. "Did not work" is meaningless unless you also explain **how** it did not work. Did you get an error message? If so, what did it say? Did it do something unexpected? Or did it not do something you think it should? Please [edit] your question to be specific about what the problem is you're asking us to help you solve. Thanks.

Comment: What results do you get if you run the select part of the query alone?

Comment: If I run the 3 beginning Declare and Select lines the command completes successfully

Comment: So This may be the issue, you are deleting records with a `WHERE location = @new_loc and circ_slip = 'waive'`...Then you try to re-enter records where `WHERE circ_slip = 'waive' and location = @copy_loc`...This appears to be only selecting records to enter where location is equal to the old location. Try switching it to `location = @new_loc` so it will enter the new records.

Answer (score 1):

Notice @copy_loc and @new_loc are defined as varchar(7), but you're putting 12 characters into them.  They're truncated and won't match the fields in the table.  Make the variables varchar(50).  Don't worry, it won't use more space than it needs.

Comment: Good point, and that would be a problem.  But the actual data I would be using consists of three-letter location codes, so I think varchar(7) is sufficient